# GUI kernel switcher similar to Manjaro

Tags: fedora, kernel, linux-kernel, manjaro

I'm now on Fedora 25 Gnome, used to be on Manjaro XFCE and what I miss the most about it is the GUI Linux switcher, so informative and easy to use. It lists installed kernels, available kernels, alpha and beta, add and remove features.

Fedora software center doesn't list kernels. Tried yumex, I might be mistaken, I have been using Fedora for few days but it doesn't list old versions nor beta versions. I have 3 kernels on my PC, and when I search for `kernel` it only shows the one I have installed, the latest stable one.

Is there a real kernel switcher besides what Manjaro provide? Or did someone port Manjaro's switcher to other distros?

Comment: If you know the name of the manjaro Gui kernel switcher package, you can certainly compile or package it for Fedora